# Why deb files are sometimes immediately gone from /var/cache/apt/archives/ after installation?

Tags: apt, package-management

I've noted sometimes after `apt install something` `deb` files are left in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` but sometimes they are gone right after installation.

I've read comprehensive explanation of install process in Ubuntu in [Why are there deb files in /var/cache/apt/archives/?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531978/why-are-there-deb-files-in-var-cache-apt-archives) but there is nothing there on how/when `deb` files get deleted from cache, it says:

> .deb package files remain cached in /var/cache/apt/archives even after
> successful installation in case they're needed for future use.

Web search gave no results to the specific question of my concern. Why sometimes `deb` files get deleted immediately after installation?

ADDED: Just before installing that `something` I manually deleted all previous `debs` from /var... maybe it mattered and the reason. Probably I should try to use `apt clean` (just read about it in https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/can-i-delete-var-cache-apt-archives-for-ubuntu-debian-linux/) instead of manual `rm`.

ADDED 2: I've just tried to run `apt clean` before installing another package - empty `/var` after install again.

Comment: They do not in my close to couple of decades of running Debian based distributions it never has happened, any time I look like just now I see the large amount of files in there all with various dates they were downloaded and installed on. Many duplicates as the versions were updated included in those files seen. I see not one shred of evidence from you to show it has occurred on your machine. Only you saying it has, how have you determined it happens?

Comment: It has happened to my system as well (Ubuntu 20.04) on several occasions.

Answer (score 3):

You have probably upgraded to a version of apt that does not keep installed packages by default, you can check by running:

```
apt-config dump | grep 'Keep-Downloaded-Packages'
```

and you will likely see:

```
Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "0";
```

If that's the case then you can keep packages again by changing that setting to 1/true:

```
echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99-keep-downloads
```